# Format with TexFAT filesystem

Tags: hard-drive, filesystems, external-hard-drive, format, transaction

Is it possible to format a device (USB stick or hard disk) with a TexFAT or TxF file system? If so, how? Is a special driver or program required for XP or Vista to be able to do this? I can find no download links, and no normal method of formating I know lists these filesystems as options.

Comment: If you mean [exFAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT), you can download [support software](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=955704) for XP. Vista SP1 already can.

Answer (score 0):

TxF (transaction aware NTFS) is not available on XP. Period.

Formatting a volume on Vista/Windows 7 with the NTFS file system gives you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

TexFAT is Transaction Aware ExFAT. From what I have heard though, its a Windows CE product.